# Show page title for all pages when we print XSLT Report using XML

Tags: xml, xslt, header, report, title

I want to print report by having PatientID in all pages as heading or title so that it will print page title in all the pages when we print
I'm not sure how to write XSLT for showing title in all pages

Below is my code

XSLT Code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

    <xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL /Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version='1.0' indent ='yes' omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <html>

     <STYLE TYPE="text/css">
     p     { line-height: "1"}
     br     { line-height: "1pt"}

     </STYLE>

     <body>

  <table >
      <xsl:for-each select="Report/PatDetails">

    <tr>

    <td align = "left" width = "250" height="50"  style="text-align: justify">
        <font name="Book Antiqua"  size="5.0"><B>

                    <xsl:call-template 
                name="substring-before-last">
                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="Value"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="marker" select="'@'" />
                </xsl:call-template>
</B>
        </font>
    </td>

      <td align = "left" width = "600" height="30">
        <font name="Book Antiqua"  size="5.0">

                <xsl:call-template 
                name="substring-after-last">
                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="Value"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="marker" select="'@'" />
                </xsl:call-template>
        </font>
      </td>

    </tr>

    </xsl:for-each>
    </table></body>

        </html>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="string-replace">
        <xsl:param name="arg"/>
        <xsl:param name="toReplace"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($arg, $toReplace)">
                <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="substring-before($arg, $toReplace)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="postfix" select="substring($arg, string- length($prefix)+string-length($toReplace)+1)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$prefix"/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;br/&      gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="arg" select="$postfix"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="toReplace" select="$toReplace"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$arg"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:template>


     <xsl:template name="substring-after-last">
     <xsl:param name="input" />
     <xsl:param name="marker" />

     <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($input,$marker)">
      <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
      <xsl:with-param name="input" 
          select="substring-after($input,$marker)" />
      <xsl:with-param name="marker" select="$marker" />
      </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select="$input" />
     </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>

     </xsl:template>


     <xsl:template name="substring-before-last">
     <xsl:param name="input" />
     <xsl:param name="marker" />

     <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="contains($input,$marker)">
      <xsl:call-template name="substring-before-last">
      <xsl:with-param name="input" 
          select="substring-before($input,$marker)" />
      <xsl:with-param name="marker" select="$marker" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$input" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:transform>
```

Below is my XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type= 'text/xsl' href = 'HNP.xsl'?>

<Report>
<PatDetails>
<Value>Patient Id:@9999</Value></PatDetails>

<Impression>
<Value>1. @Test1</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>2. @Test2</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>3. @Test3</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>4. @Test4</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>5. @Test5</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>6. @Test6</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>7. @Test7</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>8. @Test8</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>1. @Test1</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>2. @Test2</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>3. @Test3</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>4. @Test4</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>5. @Test5</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>6. @Test6</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>7. @Test7</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>8. @Test8</Value></Impression>


<Impression>
<Value>1. @Test1</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>2. @Test2</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>3. @Test3</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>4. @Test4</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>5. @Test5</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>6. @Test6</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>7. @Test7</Value></Impression>

<Impression>
<Value>8. @Test8</Value></Impression>

</Report>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to do, but it seems you need to read on XSLT. First, you need to remember that everything needs to be added to an HTML tag so that it is displayed in the style or the place you desire. Second, you need to know where to point at when referring to specific XML tags. This is a naive attempt at your rewriting your XSLT, put it in a fresh `xsl:stylesheet` tag and follow the steps to understand this attempt.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
      <head>
         <title><xsl:value-of select="PatDetails"/></title>
      </head>
      <body>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>   
   </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PatDetails/Value">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Impression/Value">
  <table border="1">
   <tr><td>                
     <xsl:for-each select=".">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </td></tr>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you Artemis I tried the XSLT given above but it's not working. Basically I want to have a report title which i want to print in all pages.If we have a patient record consists of 4 pages..I want to print patient name in all four pages as header or title to identify each page.I tried using <title> tag but it's spoiling the UI format which used to work with out that. Please let me know if you need any information Thanks Uday

Comment: What kind of output are you trying to produce? A word document, html, xml? You have put your output as xml, in which header and footer are bit strange since your data appears in one page. But I guess what you mean is you need a text file output.

Comment: Yes I want to show output in web browser using XML and layout or format using XSLT.If we click print preview on this web page you can see ------------Show page title for all pages when we print XSLT Report using XML----- as title all four pages on the top of the page.I want to do the same thing using XML and XSLT. Please let me know if you need any more information

Comment: Never mind Artemis, I can able to find the solution.

Comment: Thank you Artemis. I can able to find the answer.Anyway thank you for your time and help.Below is the answer that worked for me by modifying your answer..

Answer (score 0):

XSLT Code

```
    <head>

<title>


                        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                            <xsl:with-param name="arg" select="Report/PatDetails"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="toReplace" select="'^'"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>


</title>

</head>
```